# UWP programmatically binding dynamic form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I created a dynamic form using this model class:

```
public class CustomField 
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public CustomFieldType type { get; set; }
}
public enum CustomFieldType
{
    TEXT = 0,
    MULTI_LINE = 1,
    DATETIME = 2,
    ...
}
```

and I will use this model class to save custom field value:

```
public class CustomFieldValue
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public CustomFieldType type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("textValue")]
    public string textValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dateValue")]
    public DateTime dateValue { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

besides custom fields, my base model contains also standard inputs:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    ...

    [JsonProperty("customFieldValues")]
    public List<CustomFieldValue> customFieldValues { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how I can programmatically binding the custom fields as I did below in my view model with the standard inputs:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   BaseModel cModel;
   ...
   public string name
   {
       get
       {
           if (isLoaded)
               return Model.name;
           else
               return "";
       }
       set
       {
           if (Model.name != value)
           {
               Model.name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
               isModified = true;
           }
       }
   }
   ...
   public BaseModel Model
   {
        get
        {
            return cModel;
        }
        set
        {
            cModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(name));
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

In my view page:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName"
         Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.name, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Style="{StaticResource entryDefault}"
         Header= "Name*"
         PlaceholderText="Enter Name"
         Margin="0,10,0,0"
         Width="800"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Comment: If you want bind in code behind please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings#bindings-with-a-binding-context).

Comment: I knew that, but how I can control the OnPropertyChanged of each customField?